# test class coverage differences in sanboxes

Tags: unit-test

I have created a test class for a trigger and apex class for trigger code coverage is 80% and test class is 81% in Sandbox1.
         when I have created same test class for a trigger and apex class, for trigger code coverage is 0% and test class is 0% in another sanbox2.
         Both sanbox1 and sanbox2 are identical but I don't know why the code coverage is not happening in sanbox2. Can anyone know the reason?

Answer (score 0):

try running on query editor:

```
SELECT Id, ApexClassOrTriggerId, ApexClassOrTrigger.Name,
       NumLinesCovered, NumLinesUncovered 
  FROM ApexCodeCoverageAggregate
```

and delete all the lines that show up